# setting up ssl on rails 4 app on development mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, ruby-on-rails-4, apache2.2

I am trying to setup SSL for rails 4 app. I have successfully setup the SSL which i bought from rapidSSL.

this is my configuration file used in apache2 and rails

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    RequestHeader set X-FORWARDED-PROTO "https"
    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol all
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/server.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/server.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/intermediate.crt
    ServerPath /www
    <Directory "/var/www">
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

*config/application.rb*

```
config.force_ssl = true
```

However, when i run rails s -p 80, it just list the file structure of the folder instead of running the app. I have tried googling around and it seems that i need to use force WEBrick to use SSL but the guide i found [here](https://www.altamiracorp.com/blog/employee-posts/configuring-webrick-to-use-ssl) is only for rails 3. Hope someone could help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at this blog. Looks perry good and works for me
http://www.napcsweb.com/blog/2013/07/21/rails_ssl_simple_wa/

Comment: Didn't answer the question, although you provided a way to launch ssl, it doesn't pertain to the method of using apache and webbrick like stated in the question.